# How to use PySimpleGUI event callbacks to change the relevant button element's attributes?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to use event callbacks to flip the two colors of whichever button is pressed. I would have liked to use something similar to `window[elementkey].update(button_color=flipped_colors)`, but since I've used a lambda expression to call a function in lieu of my button keys, I am unsure how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance!

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

test1={
    'button':'1',
    'color1':'red',
    'color2':'blue',
    'key':'-button1-'
    }

test2={
    'button':'2',
    'color1':'yellow',
    'color2':'orange',
    'key':'-button2-'
    }


def button_handler(button_schema):
    
    return button_schema

col_pop =   [
            [sg.T('I AM A BOX')],
            [sg.B(button_text=test1['button'],button_color=(test1['color1'],test1['color2']),key=lambda: button_handler(test1)),
            sg.B(button_text=test2['button'],button_color=(test2['color1'],test2['color2']),key=lambda: button_handler(test2)),
            sg.B('3'),
            ]
            ]


layout_pop = [[sg.Column(col_pop,element_justification='c')]]
window_pop = sg.Window(layout=layout_pop,title='',modal=True,no_titlebar=False,font='Arial 12',resizable=True)
while True:
    event, values=window_pop.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        window_pop.close()
        break
    if callable(event):
        print(event())
        pos1, pos2 = 1,2

        colors_tup = list(event().items())
        colors_tup[pos1], colors_tup[pos2] = colors_tup[pos2], colors_tup[pos1]
        flipped_colors = colors_tup[1][1],colors_tup[2][1]
        print(flipped_colors)
```

** Edit: This allows the button to invert colors each time it's pressed, and thus solves my problem using list reversal:

```
    if event == '-1-':
        foo = window[event].ButtonColor[::-1]
        window[event].update(button_color = foo)
```

Comment: The key of element will be use as a key in a dictionary, you cannot change the value of key after element initiated. Not sure why you use a lambda function as the key of an element. To change the attributes of any element, you can do it under the event generated from button in event while-loop.

Comment: You can use dictionary to define the attributes of an element directly, like `options = {'button_text':'1', 'button_color':('red', 'blue'), 'key':'-button-'}` and use it as `sg.Button(**options)`.

Comment: I should have explained more. I use a lambda function because I need to affect around 50 buttons in the full project. I need 1 to be inverted colors and defined as "selected" while all other buttons revert to their individual, standard coloring. I found I could manually set every button's color when a button was hit, but that felt like way too much code for what I was trying to do. I chose instead to use this callback method to try and automate the process. I have no doubt there is probably an even better way to do it.

Comment: Try use option `metadata` of element to save anything about this element, even the lambda function, or state of this button. You can get/set it by `element.metadata`.